# Call state directly via salt-ssh

Tags: saltstack

Is it possible to call this state via `salt-ssh` directly?

```
vim:
  pkg.installed
```

I mean without creating an sls file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about salt-ssh but with a salt-minion you can use this command

```
salt 'minion' state.single pkg.installed name=vim
```

Comment: Yes, this works for `salt-ssh`, too. Thank you!